# Creating new column based on conditions in dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, function, dictionary, calculated-columns

This problem is from my work. I want to create a new column "referral_fee' in the data frame based on dictionary.
I have a dictionary like below:

```
referral_fees = {
        "Amazon Device Accessories": 0.45,
        "Appliances - Compact": lambda price: 0.15 if 0 < price <= 300 else 
        0.08,
        "Appliances - Full-size": 0.08,
        "Automotive and Powersports": 0.12,
        "Base Equipment Power Tools": 0.12,
        "Baby Products": lambda price: 0.08 if 0 < price <= 10 else 0.15}
```

If product is like "Appliances - Compact", there are two conditions for price as above. There is 'price' column and 'category' column in the data frame. The part of Data frame is as follows:

| ASIN | category | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Appliances - Compact | 250 |
| 2 | Appliances - Compact | 400 |
| 3 | Automotive and Powersports | 500 |
| 4 | Baby Products | 9 |
| 5 | Baby Products | 12 |
| 6 | Appliances - Full-size | 275 |

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Expected result is:

| ASIN | category | price | referral_fee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Appliances - Compact | 250 | 0.15 |
| 2 | Appliances - Compact | 400 | 0.08 |
| 3 | Automotive and Powersports | 500 | 0.12 |
| 4 | Baby Products | 9 | 0.08 |
| 5 | Baby Products | 12 | 0.15 |
| 6 | Appliances - Full-size | 275 | 0.08 |

I tried this: df["referral_fee"] = df["category"].map(referral_fees)

Another code block I tried is :

```
def referral_col(df):
    mask = df["category"].isin(referral_fees.keys())
    df.loc[mask, "referral_fee"] = df.loc[mask, "unit_sales_price"].apply(
    lambda price: referral_fees[df.loc[mask, "category"]](price))
    return df
```

first code is giving column but like this:
referral_fee

```
<function <lambda> at 0x000001EAFE8CE040>
<function <lambda> at 0x000001EAFE8CE040>
<function <lambda> at 0x000001EAFE8CE040>
```

and second code block is giving me the error if I input the df in the function referral_col which is:
unhashable type: 'Series'

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
df['referral_fee'] = df['category'].apply(lambda x: referral_fees.get(x, np.nan)(0) if isinstance(referral_fees[x], type(lambda:None)) else referral_fees[x])
```

Here, `referral_fees.get(x, np.nan)(0)` returns the lambda function's result if the dictionary value is a lambda function and the key `x` exists in the dictionary. If the key does not exist, then a `NaN` is returned.

Not calling the lambda function by some dummy argument which in this case is `(0)` returns the lambda function objects resulting in the issue you raised.

As commented by [@chandrashekhar-bagul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20820693/chandrashekhar-bagul), another approach that works is

```
df['referral_fee'] = df['category'].apply(lambda x: referral_fees.get(x, np.nan)(0) if callable(referral_fees.get(x)) else referral_fees.get(x, np.nan))
```

Comment: Thanks. But it is giving me the syntax error at type(lambda)).

Comment: I found the solution using function called 'callable()'